# How can I jump to some column after current one in excel

Tags: excel

For example if the cursor is on "B5" cell, I want to jump 20 column after that, which is "V5" cell.
I want to move relative to the current cell so I cannot use "go to"
If it is not possible, it is helpful to find a way to move to a specific column but in the same row.

Comment: You need to hitch the move to an event. The most likely event would be the Worksheet_Change event. Something like "if B5 is changed jump to B25" (but that is definitely not in the same "row" as you put it). You might also stipulate the jump when the user enters a tab in B5 or a "j". Or you might use a keyboard shortcut that jumps to B25 from anywhere on the sheet when activated. It all depends on your work flow.

Comment: Do you mean 20 Rows, as in _`B5` cell, I want to jump ... , which is `B25` _ or 20 Columns, which would be `B5` to `V5`

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in the question and thanks for the notes. I use R1C1 reference style so both columns and rows are indicated by numbers but I wanted to write the question in the way which be clear but I made the mistake. Exactly as you guessed I want to move to "V5" from "B5" cell (in the same row)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, using this simple VBA macro:

```
Sub Jump_20()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Select
End Sub
```

`Offset(Row, Column)` refers to the cell, `Row` rows further, `Column` columns further.

Comment: OP's Q is unclear.  They say _... "B5" cell, I want to jump 20 column after that, which is "B25" ..._.  So that would be 20 _Rows_, ie `ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0).Select`   Columns would be `B5` to `V5`